# How do I split my graph into +/- on the x axis? (meaning show negatives to the left of zero and positive comments to the right)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to split my graph so into +/- on the x axis... meaning show negatives to the left of zero and positive comments to the right. Right now, they are all lumped together. When we do this it's important that the "count of occurrences" is still reflected like in the original graph.

Here is my head(df)

```
> head(df)
   Journey.Area Experience.Framework Postive.or.Negative
1    Installing     People/Associate                   1
2 Using Product            Execution                  -1
3    Installing     People/Associate                   1
4      Delivery            Execution                  -1
5    Installing     People/Associate                  -1
6      Delivery     People/Associate                   1
```

Here is my put(head(df))

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Journey.Area = c("Installing", "Using Product", 
"Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", "Delivery"), Experience.Framework = c("People/Associate", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate"), Postive.or.Negative = c(1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code for the current graph. How do I change it so that it graphs the Positive.or.Negative one direction of zero or the other as applicable:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
      mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
  levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
             "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
             "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  count(Journey.Area,Experience.Framework) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Journey.Area,n,fill=Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(fill="", x="Customer Journey Area", y="User Experience Framework") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Output:
[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will work for you?

```r
df %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  summarise(score = n() * Postive.or.Negative) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = score, y = Journey.Area, fill = Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2), labels = abs) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(x = 'Negative Comments        Positive Comments')
```

[image]

Comment: I think that is close! I'm getting a warning when I run it though: Warning message:
Removed 79 rows containing missing values (geom_col)

Comment: @M.Carter remove the `scale_x_continuous` line and that should vanish. It was just to make this example prettier!

Answer (score 0):

First I removed your `count` command and change the `geom_col` to `geom_bar` where I added `stat="identity"`. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
                               levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
                                          "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
                                          "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Journey.Area,Postive.or.Negative,fill=Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(fill="", x="Customer Journey Area", y="User Experience Framework") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is close, but we have now lost the "count values". Can we change this so it shows the count of occurrence (like the original graph) but the negative counts go to the left and the positive counts go to the right?

Comment: Very odd, it runs in the original and is the first column. Did you try copy/paste to see if it's a typing error?

Comment: My bad was my mistake. But when using `count` it returns no negative values?

Comment: Right, I think it's something in the code that's messing us up. In the original code for the graph, we get an accurate count of the grouping occurrences. Ideally, we just separate this out based on if it's +/- (column 3) and then show the negative ones going left and and the positive ones going right. Positive.or.Negative is either -1 or +1 and nothing in between